# HTML CSS images with background borders

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to create borders like in given below link using css.
http://themeforest.net/item/midway-responsive-travel-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/3559006?ref=magazinehive

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: you need a background image

Comment: Tell us what you have tried first and then we can help you. We cant just write the code for you, where's the fun in that?

Comment: image with hover types i tried using css but its not looks like in the given link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `background-image` and put your image into.

**OR**

Create some rectangulars div with different `z-index`.
After use this css property `rotate` on each rectangular div.

```
-moz-transform:rotate(-10deg); //firefox
-webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg); //Chrome, Safari
-o-transform:rotate(-10deg); //Opera
```

Example on this website : http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/create-the-illusion-of-stacked-elements-with-css3-pseudo-elements/

Answer (score 0):

That is an illusion. Not every picture got this frame, they just got a background image with that border and they place every content inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireBug or Chrome's developer tool to find out how they achieve that. What they did is creating multiple div and use CSS transform to rotate the div in different degree to create the effect.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ChbP7/

HTML Code:

```
<div style="padding: 20px;">
    <div class="main-slider-container fade-slider-container">
        <div class="fade-slider main-slider fade-effect">
            <div style="background-color: #EEE; height: 100px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-background layer-1"></div>
        <div class="block-background layer-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-slider {
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-slider-container .block-background {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.fade-slider {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.fade-slider-container {
    position: relative;
}

.main-slider,
.fade-slider-container .block-background {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.fade-slider-container .layer-1 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(1.2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(1.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1.2deg);
    transform: rotate(1.2deg);
}

.fade-slider-container .layer-2 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-1.8deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-1.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1.8deg);
    transform: rotate(-1.8deg);
}
```